# Link not showing in dropbox chooser app

Tags: javascript, html, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm struggling trying to get a link to pop up in in the Dropbox chooser drop-in app. I'm using the javascript method and inserting into an html page. The dropbox chooser button shows up, and I'm able to select a file from the dropbox pop-up window, but the result is just a green checkmark and NO link like in the demo (I've tried both the direct and preview method). I've been struggling with this for a few hours. Anyone see anything wrong, or have a good code snipeet they want to share?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="XXXXXX"></script> 
<!-- Replace data-app-key with yours --> <script type="text/javascript">
// add an event listener to a Chooser button
document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
    function(e) {
        alert("Here's the chosen file: " + e.files[0].link)
        window.location.href = 'e.files[0].link';
    }, false);
</script> 
<input data-link-type="direct" id="db-chooser" name="selected-file" type="dropbox-chooser" />
<div id="link-div" style="display: none">Link:</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
function(e) {
  var link = document.getElementById("link");
  link.textContent = link.href = e.files[0].link;
  document.getElementById("link-div").style.display = "block";
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues in the above code.

1. The first script references `db-chooser` before it's actually on the page, so that may not be working at all.
2. The second script looks for an element called `link`, but I think you mean `link-div`.

Finally, you might want to update to the latest version of `dropins.js`, just because it's the latest. :-) The `input` tag version has gone away, and instead you can use `createChooseButton`. Here's a complete working example using the latest version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="XXXXXX"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <a id="link"></a>

    <script>
        var button = Dropbox.createChooseButton({
            success: function(files) {
                var linkTag = document.getElementById('link');
                linkTag.href = files[0].link;
                linkTag.textContent = files[0].link;
            },
            linkType: 'direct'
        });
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```